# How to extend Link and NavLink with same styles using Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

New to Styled Components and I'm trying to figure out a better way to extend and share styles.

I have something like:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const StyledNavLink = styled(Link)`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
`;

const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

Is there a way to define the same proper only once for both components?

**EDIT:** I think I have *one* way to do it (using [css helper function](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css))

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const sharedStyle = css`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
`

const StyledNavLink = styled(Link)`
  ${sharedStyle}
`;

const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  ${sharedStyle}
`;
```

Comment: It's a good way with `sharedStyle` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is the way from your answer:

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const sharedStyle = css`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
`

const StyledNavLink = styled(Link)`
  ${sharedStyle}
`;

const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  ${sharedStyle}
`;
```

The other could be to create a dedicated function:

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const withLinkStyles = (component) => styled(component)`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
`;

const StyledNavLink = withLinkStyles(Link);
const StyledNavLink = withLinkStyles(NavLink);
```

I would choose the first one, as it seems more expressive and in-line with the declarative way `styled-components` authors intended the library to be used.